# Excel Custom Ribbon button calling subroutines for other ribbon buttons

Tags: vba, excel, ribbonx

If i set up a subroutine so that it can be called from a customer ribbon button is it still possible to call those subroutines from other subroutines? I'm getting the argument not optional error message but I'm not sure what argument to pass to the subroutine since I'm not calling then from the ribbon button but from inside another subroutine itself.

```
Sub Reset(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    Call ResetForumlas
    Call ResetValues
End Sub

Sub ResetForumlas(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    "Do some stuff"
End Sub

Sub ResetValues(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    "Do Some more stuff"
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try its with out the call. Like this

```
Sub Reset(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    ResetForumlas
    ResetValues
End Sub

Sub ResetForumlas(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    "Do some stuff"
End Sub

Sub ResetValues(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    "Do Some more stuff"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an old post but if someone arrive here... try this:

```
Sub Reset(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    Call ResetForumlas
    Call ResetValues
End Sub

sub test
    dim ribboncontrol as IRibbonControl
    call Reset (ribboncontrol)
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the argument as an optional variable works great in that situation:

```
Sub Reset(Optional ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    ResetForumlas
    ResetValues
End Sub

Sub ResetForumlas(Optional ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    "Do some stuff"
End Sub

Sub ResetValues(Optional ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    "Do Some more stuff"
End Sub
```

Comment: You can also create new routines to assign to the ribbon controls that do nothing but call your other routines. Those can then be called from anywhere since they don't need the IRibbonControl argument.

Answer (score 0):

I always add an _onAction suffix to the subs called by the ribbon - to identify them accordingly

Then the Subs that are doing the work can be called with a name that describes what they are doing.

```vb
Sub ResetAll_onAction(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    ResetForumlas
    ResetValues
End Sub

Sub ResetFormulas_onAction(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    resetFormulas
End Sub

Sub ResetValues_onAction(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    resetValues
End Sub

Public Sub resetFormulas()
   'Do some stuff
End Sub

Public Sub resetValues()
   'Do other stuff
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Application.run" instead of "Call". It helps when sub-s are located in different modules. in this case you should add a module name too ("Module1.ResetFormulas").

```
Sub Reset(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
    Application.run "ResetForumlas"
    Application.run "ResetValues" 
End Sub
```

Note that sub names shoud be in string format.